# Chrome/Java/Selenium4: authentication popup with RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver, selenium4

I want to do some Java/Selenium4 test automation on a test-environment, which is protected by an authentication popup. This is not an alert, it's a Chrome popup: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El80a.png).

In our framework we have two options:

1. You run the test on your local machine. We use an org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver class to drive Chrome.
2. The test is run on our CI/docker machine (using maven and selenium/chrome containers). Then we drive Chrome (in the selenium container) from the maven container with an org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver class.

This setup has always worked fine. This popup, however, proves to be quite a challenge. I found a solution for option 1:

`((HasAuthentication)driver).register(UsernameAndPassword.of("username","password"));`

This does not work for Option 2, because apparently the RemoteWebDriver class does not implement the HasAuthentication interface:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.HasAuthentication (org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver and org.openqa.selenium.HasAuthentication are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

This means that this solution won't run on our CI setup, and now I'm stuck. I see people using custom Chrome extensions as workaround, but I'm hoping there is an easier/nicer solution...

How can I interact with a browser-popup, with Selenium4/Java, using a RemoteWebDriver Chrome driver class?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ChromeDevToolsAugmenterAuthentication {


public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException,InterruptedException {
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
WebDriver driver = RemoteWebDriver.builder()
  .oneOf(chromeOptions)
  .address("http://localhost:4444")
  .build(); 
DevTools devTools = ((HasDevTools) driver).getDevTools();
devTools.createSession();

Augmenter augmenter = new Augmenter();

driver = augmenter
  .addDriverAugmentation("chrome",
                         HasAuthentication.class,
                         (caps, exec) -> (whenThisMatches, useTheseCredentials) ->
                           devTools.getDomains()
                             .network()
                             .addAuthHandler(whenThisMatches, useTheseCredentials))
  .augment(driver);

((HasAuthentication) driver).register(UsernameAndPassword.of("admin", "admin"));
driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth");
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.tagName("p")).getText());
driver.quit();
```

}
}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.